# MySQL check constraint violation

Tags: mysql, sql, check-constraints

I'm creating a MySQL database using the Oracle SQL Developer.

I have created a table for currencies where the `Currency_Code` column should contain a three character (alphabets only), capitalised currency code.

When I try to add a value it says that the constraint `CHK_Currency_Code_1` has been violated, but I'm not sure why.

I'm quite new to SQL. Here is the script:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Currency (
    Currency_Code CHAR(3) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    PRIMARY KEY ( Currency_Code ),
    CONSTRAINT CHK_Currency_Code_1 CHECK ( Currency_Code LIKE '[a-z][a-z][a-z]' ),
    CONSTRAINT CHK_Currency_Code_2 CHECK ( Currency_Code = UPPER( Currency_Code ) )
);

INSERT INTO Currency (Currency_Code)
VALUES ('USD');
```

Comment: Looks like your db is case sensitive.

Comment: @HoneyBadger yeah, I want the Currency_Code to be capitalised, but the USD value which I added is capitalised too so I'm not sure if that's the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply USE REGEXP instead of LIKE. You are using regular expression but with LIKE function, that was the error.

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Currency (
        Currency_Code CHAR(3) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        PRIMARY KEY ( Currency_Code ),
        CONSTRAINT CHK_Currency_Code_1 CHECK ( Currency_Code REGEXP '[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]' ),
        CONSTRAINT CHK_Currency_Code_2 CHECK ( Currency_Code = UPPER( Currency_Code ) )
    );
    
    INSERT INTO Currency (Currency_Code)
    VALUES ('USD');
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regex constraint,

`CONSTRAINT CHK_Currency_Code_1 CHECK ( Currency_Code LIKE '[a-z][a-z][a-z]' )`

Only allows for lowercase, convert it to allow only for uppercase.

`CONSTRAINT CHK_Currency_Code_1 CHECK ( Currency_Code LIKE '[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]' )`

Now when you run your insertion, it will pass as 'USD' is uppercase.

Comment: It will also make CHK_Currency_Code_2 superfluous.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried that but it's still saying that it has been violated, is there any alternatives?

Comment: Try removing the second constraint, make sure the table does not already exist prior to creation as it may be validating against the old rules before we changed the code.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, you would use regular expressions:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Currency (
    Currency_Code CHAR(3) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    PRIMARY KEY ( Currency_Code ),
    CONSTRAINT CHK_Currency_Code_1 CHECK ( Currency_Code REGEXP '^[A-Z]{3}$' )
);
```

This assumes that the collation is not case-insensitive.

If you want to insist on case-sensitivity, you can use `BINARY`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Currency (
    Currency_Code CHAR(3) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    PRIMARY KEY ( Currency_Code ),
    CONSTRAINT CHK_Currency_Code_1 CHECK ( BINARY Currency_Code REGEXP BINARY '^[A-Z]{3}$' )
);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8807c132810ff78a0711f99da9c3ccce) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: alternatively, set the collation: `Currency_Code CHAR(3) COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL UNIQUE`.  adding BINARY to the constraint will not allow e.g. USD to be entered, but will find USD when selecting where Currency_Code='usd'; it's unclear if this is wanted or not